# Magento 2: RequireJS not working in Payment Method

Tags: magento2

I trying to use requireJS in my custom payment method, but its not working..

**cc-form.html :**

```
    <script>
require([
          'jquery',
      ], function ($) {
        jQuery(function(){              

            $("vtoken").focus(function(){
            alert('ok');
            });

       });
});
</script>

<fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items ccard ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
     <!-- ko if: (isShowLegend())-->
     <legend class="legend">
         <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Credit Card Information'--><!-- /ko --></span>
     </legend><br />
     <!-- /ko -->
     <div class="field type">
         <div class="control">
             <ul class="credit-card-types">
                 <!-- ko foreach: {data: getCcAvailableTypesValues(), as: 'item'} -->
                 <li class="item" data-bind="css: {
                                                  _active: $parent.selectedCardType() == item.value,
                                                  _inactive: $parent.selectedCardType() != null && $parent.selectedCardType() != item.value
                                                  } ">
                     <!--ko if: $parent.getIcons(item.value) -->
                     <img data-bind="attr: {
                         'src': $parent.getIcons(item.value).url,
                         'alt': item.type,
                         'width': $parent.getIcons(item.value).width,
                         'height': $parent.getIcons(item.value).height
                         }">
                     <!--/ko-->
                 </li>
                 <!--/ko-->
             </ul>
             <input type="hidden"
                    name="payment[cc_type]"
                    class="input-text"
                    value=""
                    data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_cc_type', 'data-container': getCode() + '-cc-type'},
                    value: creditCardType
                    ">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="field number required">
        <!-- X -->
        <input type="text" name="payment[vtoken]" class="input-text" value="" id="vtoken" />      
        <!-- X -->


.....
.....
....
```

I am not able to figure out why my jquery is not loading.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can call script at end of the phtml file ,once it is working fine you can shift the `script` into javascript file , here i added working example in my phtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
        //alert('jquery working');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Make sure you are going step by step means go with `alert` first , then you can go with `events` like `focus`

Hope this helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can't call script inside html file. you have to define your js inside custom js file.
You have issue regarding call js inside template file.

This is not phtml file its only template file with html extension.
In magento with html extension file if you define your js its not executed from this file.

You must required your js declaration inside js file or phtml file to working with it.

After delacared inside js file you have to run command for deployment.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first you are calling id of input field that are called with `#` and also add it js code after the field.

```
<script>
require([
          'jquery',
      ], function ($) {
        $(function(){              

            $("#vtoken").focus(function(){
            alert('ok');
            });

       });
});
</script>
```

and rest you have to deploy @Rakesh answer